# Rhomobile, playing a video local storage

Tags: android, video, local-storage, rhomobile, rhodes

Hi I am trying to play a mp4 or mp3 file from local storage, I know how to play the video when it is on a web server. These files are downloaded and stored in my data app directory.

I store the details in an array called @Attachments. I then have the following code to display the details of each attachment.

```
        @attachments.each do |att|
          if att.MimeType=~ /image/
            %> <img src="<%=att.Data%>" height="100" width="100" alt="Attachment Image"> </img> 
            <br/><br/>
            <% elsif att.MimeType=~ /video/ %>
            <p> File Location - <%= att.Data %> </p>
            <a href="<%= att.Data %>">Play Video - <%= att.Title %></a><br/><br/><%
          else
            %>
            <a href="">View Attachment - <%= att.Title %></a><br/><br/><%
          end
        end
      %>
  <p>
```

So as  you can see I am checking what the file types are an displaying them, I can display an image no problem. But when I click the link to play the video I get a error loading page or a page that just has undefined. I know where the file is located with the att.Data which gives the directory to the file which is as follows. /data/data/com.rhomobile.appname/rhodata/apps/filename.extension

Any help here would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to launch a video on click of a hyperlink using following approach:

Attached a jquery script to handle hyperlink click event. On the click event, called a method on the controllers created in RhoMobile and passed the video path as parameter. The code looks like:

```
<a href="#" id="hyperlink_id">
  <script>
     $('#hyperlink_id').click(function () {
         $.get("/app/Collateral/playmedia?medianame=path_to_video",
           function(data) {});
           }); 
  </script>
  <img src="<%=@collateralHM[iconName].fileName%>">
</a>
```

In the controller class, the code to handle this looks like:

```
# GET /Collateral/playvideo
def playvideo
  mediaName = @params['medianame']    
  System.open_url mediaName
end
```

Hope this helps.